# using pd.read_sql() to extract large data (>5 million records) from oracle database, making the sql execution very slow

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle, pandasql

1. Initially tried using pd.read_sql().
2. Then I tried using sqlalchemy, query objects but none of these methods are 
   useful as the sql getting executed for long time and it never ends.
3. I tried using Hints.
4. I guess the problem is the following: Pandas creates a cursor object in the 
   background. With cx_Oracle we cannot influence the "arraysize" parameter which 
   will be used thereby, i.e. always the default value of 100 will be used which 
   is far too small.

   ```
   CODE:

     import pandas as pd
     import Configuration.Settings as CS
     import DataAccess.Databases as SDB
     import sqlalchemy
     import cx_Oracle

     dfs = []

     DBM = SDB.Database(CS.DB_PRM,PrintDebugMessages=False,ClientInfo="Loader")

     sql = '''
                                 WITH            
                                     l AS
                                   (
                                   SELECT DISTINCT /*+ materialize */
                                     hcz.hcz_lwzv_id AS lwzv_id

                                   FROM
                                     pm_mbt_materialbasictypes mbt
                                     INNER JOIN pm_mpt_materialproducttypes mpt ON mpt.mpt_mbt_id = mbt.mbt_id
                                     INNER JOIN pm_msl_materialsublots msl ON msl.msl_mpt_id = mpt.mpt_id
                                     INNER JOIN pm_historycompattributes hca ON hca.hca_msl_id = msl.msl_id AND hca.hca_ignoreflag = 0 
                                     INNER JOIN pm_tpm_testdefprogrammodes tpm ON tpm.tpm_id = hca.hca_tpm_id 
                                     inner join pm_tin_testdefinsertions tin on tin.tin_id = tpm.tpm_tin_id             
                                     INNER JOIN pm_hcz_history_comp_zones hcz ON hcz.hcz_hcp_id = hca.hca_hcp_id
                                   WHERE
                                     mbt.mbt_name = :input1 and tin.tin_name = 'x1' and
                                    hca.hca_testendday < '2018-5-31' and hca.hca_testendday > '2018-05-30'                  
                                   ),
                               TPL as 
                                   (
                                   select /*+ materialize */
                                     *
                                     from
                                     (
                                     select
                                       ut.ut_id,
                                       ut.ut_basic_type,
                                       ut.ut_insertion,
                                       ut.ut_testprogram_name,
                                       ut.ut_revision  
                                     from
                                       pm_updated_testprogram ut
                                     where 
                                       ut.ut_basic_type = :input1 and ut.ut_insertion = :input2 
                                     order by
                                       ut.ut_revision desc  
                                     ) where rownum = 1
                                   )

                                   SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */
                                     rcl.rcl_lotidentifier                                           AS LOT, 
                                     lwzv.lwzv_wafer_id                                              AS WAFER,
                                     pzd.pzd_zone_name                                               AS ZONE,
                                     tte.tte_tpm_id||'~'||tte.tte_testnumber||'~'||tte.tte_testname  AS Test_Identifier,
                                     case when ppd.ppd_measurement_result > 1e15 then NULL else SFROUND(ppd.ppd_measurement_result,6) END AS Test_Results

                                  FROM
                                     TPL 
                                     left JOIN pm_pcm_details pcm on pcm.pcm_ut_id = TPL.ut_id 
                                     left JOIN pm_tin_testdefinsertions tin ON tin.tin_name = TPL.ut_insertion 
                                     left JOIN pm_tpr_testdefprograms tpr ON tpr.tpr_name = TPL.ut_testprogram_name and tpr.tpr_revision = TPL.ut_revision
                                     left JOIN pm_tpm_testdefprogrammodes tpm ON tpm.tpm_tpr_id = tpr.tpr_id and tpm.tpm_tin_id = tin.tin_id 
                                     left JOIN pm_tte_testdeftests tte on tte.tte_tpm_id = tpm.tpm_id and tte.tte_testnumber = pcm.pcm_testnumber 
                                     cross join l 
                                     left JOIN pm_lwzv_info lwzv ON lwzv.lwzv_id = l.lwzv_id 
                                     left JOIN pm_rcl_resultschipidlots rcl ON rcl.rcl_id = lwzv.lwzv_rcl_id                                   
                                     left JOIN pm_pcm_zone_def pzd ON pzd.pzd_basic_type = TPL.ut_basic_type and pzd.pzd_pcm_x = lwzv.lwzv_pcm_x and pzd.pzd_pcm_y = lwzv.lwzv_pcm_y 
                                     left JOIN pm_pcm_par_data ppd ON ppd.ppd_lwzv_id = l.lwzv_id and ppd.ppd_tte_id = tte.tte_id

       '''
   #method1: using query objects.

   Q = DBM.getQueryObject(sql)
   Q.execute({"input1":'xxxx',"input2":'yyyy'})

   while not Q.AtEndOfResultset:
     print Q

   #method2: using sqlalchemy

    connectstring = "oracle+cx_oracle://username:Password@(description= 
    (address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=tnsconnect string) 
    (port=pertnumber)))(connect_data=(sid=xxxx)))"
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectstring, arraysize=10000)
    df_p = pd.read_sql(sql, params= 
    {"input1":'xxxx',"input2":'yyyy'}, con=engine)

   #method3: using pd.read_sql()

   df_p = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_PCM, params= 
   {"input1":'xxxx',"input2":'yyyy'}, 
   coerce_float=True, con= DBM.Connection)
   ```

It would be great if some one could help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the reason why the execution is slow, it is due to this line in sql                    
" case when ppd.ppd_measurement_result > 1e15 then NULL else SFROUND(ppd.ppd_measurement_result,6) END AS Test_Results".

Comment: Function which I am calling is:                                                                                         CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sfround(num IN float, sf IN int) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
    RETURN case WHEN num < -1e20 THEN -1e20 WHEN num > 1e20 THEN 1e20 when num = 0 then 0 else round(num ,sf-1-floor(log(10,abs(num)))) END;
END;

Comment: can anyone tell how to adjust this when the number is negative and it is e-15 range? Think the function is unable to handle this. This is my guess, I may be wrong. Need your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another possibility to adjust the array size without needing to create oraaccess.xml as suggested by Chris. This may not work with the rest of your code as is, but it should give you an idea of how to proceed if you wish to try this approach!

```
class Connection(cx_Oracle.Connection):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Connection, self).__init__("user/pw@dsn")

    def cursor(self):
        c = super(Connection, self).cursor()
        c.arraysize = 5000
        return c

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(creator=Connection)
pandas.read_sql(sql, engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative to experiment with.

Set a prefetch size by using the external configuration available to Oracle Call Interface programs like cx_Oracle.  This overrides internal settings used by OCI programs.  Create an oraaccess.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <oraaccess xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess"
  xmlns:oci="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess"
  schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess
  http://xmlns.oracle.com/oci/oraaccess.xsd">
  <default_parameters>
    <prefetch>
      <rows>1000</rows>
    </prefetch>
  </default_parameters>
</oraaccess>
```

If you use tnsnames.ora or sqlnet.ora for cx_Oracle, then put the oraaccess.xml file in the same directory.  Otherwise, create a new directory and set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to that directory name.

cx_Oracle needs to be using Oracle Client 12c, or later, libraries.

Experiment with different sizes.

See [OCI Client-Side Deployment Parameters Using oraaccess.xml](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-9D12F489-EC02-46BE-8CD4-5AECED0E2BA2).