# Using cx_Oracle How Can I speed-up Oracle Query to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I have python code that reads a very large Oracle db of unknown row numbers to extract some data confined by lat/lon guidelines but it takes about 20 minutes per query. I am trying to re-write or add something to my code to improve this efficiency time since i have many queries to run one at a time. Here is my code that i'm using now:

```
plant_name = 'NEW HARVEST'

conn= cx_Oracle.connect('DOMINA_CONSULTA/password@ex021-orc.corp.companyname.com:1540/domp_domi_bi')
try:
    query1 = '''
         SELECT * FROM DOMINAGE.DGE_RAYOS WHERE FECHA_RAYO >= '01-JAN-19' AND FECHA_RAYO < '01-JAN- 
         20' AND COORDENADA_X>=41.82 AND COORDENADA_X<=42.52 AND COORDENADA_Y>=-95.83 AND 
         COORDENADA_Y<=-95.13
     '''
dfp = pd.read_sql(con = conn, sql = query1)

finally:
    conn.close()
dfp.head()

#drop col's not needed
dfp = dfp[['FECHA_RAYO','INTENSIDAD_KA','COORDENADA_X','COORDENADA_Y']] 
dfp = dfp.assign(SITE=plant_name)
```

Comment: Don't do a `SELECT *` only to drop columns later.  Just query the columns you need. Once you've tuned the SQL (and indexes etc), look at increasing `arraysize` if you are fetching a large number of rows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693530/using-pd-read-sql-to-extract-large-data-5-million-records-from-oracle-datab  Also see https://oralytics.com/2018/11/14/reading-data-from-oracle-table-into-python-pandas-how-long-different-arraysize/ and https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html

Comment: Also do not use dates in "human" format, use ANSI [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1): `FECHA_RAYO >= date '2019-01-01'`. It doesn't depend on any settings in DB/session.

Comment: I must use dates in this format since that is the format of the dates i'm reading in the db (01-JAN-19). i tried your example and received an error while running code.